# Gosu: How to resize an image to fit window?

Tags: ruby, drawing, libgosu

Using Ruby Gosu, I'm drawing an image this way:

```
@background_image.draw(0, 0, 0)
```

The image is larger than the window, is there a way to magically resize it to fit the window? I'm trying to avoid hardcoding `factor_x` and `factor_y`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate factor_x\factor_y with something like this (assuming your window is stored in @window)

```
fx = @window.width/@background_image.width
fy = @window.height/@background_image.height
@background_image.draw(0, 0, 0, fx, fy)
```

Or use a draw_as_quad method, but it's slightly more verbose
(http://www.libgosu.org/rdoc/Gosu/Image.html#draw_as_quad-instance_method)

```
@background_image.draw_as_quad(0, 0, 0xffffffff, @window.width, 0, 0xffffffff, @window.width, @window.height, 0xffffffff, 0, @window.height, 0xffffffff, 0)
```

Comment: Oh, man! I missed that Sesame Street chapter! Division, sweet.